# visual studio: what is sourcesafe?

Tags: c#, ide, visual-sourcesafe

what is sourcesafe?

i am trying to download it to see if it will work well with c# because someone told me to download it for a job, but i don't even understand what it is?

is it built into the visual studio ide or what?

Comment: Fortunately, SourceSafe is dead.

Comment: I hope the programmer that told you this didn't know "sourcesafe" from "source control" or "version control" and that's what you're after.  If however they actually meant source safe and you have to connect to that server, stop, gather your stuff, run like the wind, don't look back.

Comment: I am surprised you can still download it.  Microsoft just recently announced that support will end in April of next year.  It is offically dead...finally!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SourceSafe is a poor and obsolete [source control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_control).
It can store an application's source code and show revision history, and allow multiple developers to work on the same project efficiently.

It has been replaced by [Team Foundation Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server).

Answer (score 4):

Sourcesafe is a version control system from Microsoft, some would say not a very good one. It's not part of Visual studio however it does integrate into it. MS have now replaced VSS in their Team System version of Visual Studio.

Source control is a great idea, and experience with them will definitely help your Job hunting, but don't constrain yourself to Sourcesafe, also checkout (pun intended) systems like Subversion etc.

Comment: TFS isn't a competing product - it's a replacement. SourceSafe is dead. It's no longer necessary to compete with it.

Comment: @John, thats like saying VB6 is dead because VB.NET replaces it. It's only true when the legacy stuff is finally gone....I know too many poor bas^&ds who still have to put up with VSS on a day to day basis.

Comment: for anyone considering using either product for new development, both VSS and VB6 should be considered dead. We should not confuse the issue, or some poor souls will read this and decide that it's a good idea to _start_ developing using VB6 and VSS!

Comment: @John, Sure. I hope that no-one got the implication from what I said that it was a good idea for greenfields dev, that was never my intent. Just for clarification I'll update the answer.